# MVC 5: How to show a string instead of number in the views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm brand new to this. Using MVC 5, on .NET 4.5.1, and Entity FrameWork 6.1.3. I started off with an Oracle database.

There is a field called Activity that is currently a decimal field. I want to show "Inactive" or "Active" depending on if it is a 0 or 1.

I can do this in the View with an If statement, but I have views for Index, Edit, Details, and Create that I would have to modify and in the case of the Edit and Create views, I would then need to take the input and convert it back to a decimal.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Model:

```
[DisplayName("Active")]
    public decimal? ACTIVE { get; set; }
```

View:

```
@if (Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ACTIVE).Equals("0"))
{
   @:Inactive
}
else
{
   @:Active
}
```

Comment: If you concern is repeating layout code, look into using the `[UIHint]` attribute on your model. https://www.iambacon.co.uk/blog/use-display-and-editor-templates-ftw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By taking advantage of HTML Helpers, you can reduce the amount of tedious typing of HTML tags that you must perform to create a standard HTML page

**Example code as per your requirement:**

In your View:

```
@Html.ActiveOrInactive(item.ACTIVE)
```

Helper extension code:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActiveOrInactive(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, decimal invNo)
{
    var text = (invNo == 0) ? "InActive" : "Active";
    return new MvcHtmlString(text);
}
```

Note: didn't test the code and hope it will work

**For more info about Helper extension**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs

Comment: Cool. I didn't know about this technique. This should be useful.

Answer (score 0):

In Model, for decimal property, you can write custom code for both set and get, there would be no need for making changes to the view whatsoever.

```
    get
    {
        return this.isActive==1? "Active":"InActive";
    }
    set
    {
        this.isActive = value=="Active"?1:0;
    }
```

Else use enum for this property!

Comment: oh nice. I was thinking that this would need to be done at the model level. I'll give this a shot.

Comment: Update:  It doesn't seem to work. It doesn't let me return a string for the get or test for a string value in the set. "Cannot implicitly convert type string to type decimal." and "Operator == cannot be applied to operands of type decimal and string".

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a method for converting from a decimal to a string and vice versa and use it on your View and/or Controller.

```
public static string DisplayStatus(decimal? number)
{
    return number == 1 ? "Active" : "Inactive";
}

public static decimal ConvertStatus(string status)
{
    return status == "Active" ? 1 : 0;
}
```